# counting in bits function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print the max number of bits (n) and also the max number those number of bits are able to represent. I feel as though the problem is in the `x = x%2`

input:

```
sortbit(3)
```

output:

```
000
111
000
111
000
111
000
111
```

expected output"

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

my code:

```
def sortbit(n):
    max_num = 2**n

    for x in range(0,max_num):
        stringy = []
        a = 0
        while a < n:
            a += 1
            x = x % 2
            if x == 0:
                stringy.insert(a,'0')
            else:
                stringy.insert(a,'1')
        t = ''.join(stringy)
        print t
```

Comment: Want to take a shortcut? `["".join(item) for item in itertools.product(("01"), repeat=3)]`

Comment: correctly if I am using this term wrong. This is quite pythonic? lol

Comment: Or use format:  `for i in range(2**3): print format(i,'03b')`

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Nope...check again.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: I'll go wear a paper bag now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are turning any number into either `1` or `0` with `x = x % 2`. You may as well just print `str(x % 2) * n`.

You need to use integer division instead, and test separately for even or odd.

Even better, you could just append the *output* of the modulus test, as string, to `stringy`:

```
stringy.insert(0, str(x % 2))
x = x // 2
```

Demo with the code simplified a bit:

```
>>> def sortbit(n):
...     max_num = 2**n
...     for x in range(max_num):
...         stringy = []
...         for a in range(n):
...             stringy.append(str(x % 2))
...             x //= 2
...         print ''.join(reversed(stringy))
... 
>>> sortbit(3)
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

You could also bitshift the value; the [`>>` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) moves the bits to the right for you by a given number of steps; `x >> 1` shifts the bits in `x` one step over, essentially dividing by two.

You could also look into the [`bin()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) (returns the value as a binary string, starting with `0b`), and the [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format), together with the [`str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), which lets you format values as binary strings as well using the `b` output format. Printing your values in a loop could be as simple as:

```
def sortbit(n):
    for i in range(2**n):
        print '{:0{}b}'.format(i, n)
```

Last but not least, you are simply producing the product of the digits 0 and 1, `n` times. You could express that with [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) as well:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for bits in product('01', repeat=3):
...     print ''.join(bits)
... 
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

but that could be seen as cheating. :-)

Comment: how are you so good at python... when will i reach this level

Comment: `range(n**2-1)` is wrong...n of 4 will be print 0-14 decimal.

Comment: This page is changing too quickly :)

Comment: Do try to keep up! :-P

Answer (score 2):

You've got answers for your specific code, so here's a solution using Python's `format` to print `n` digits of binary with the appropriate number of leading zeroes:

```
>>> def sortbit(n):
...  for i in range(2**n):
...   print '{0:0{1}b}'.format(i,n)
...
>>> sortbit(2)
00
01
10
11
>>> sortbit(3)
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's actual output.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, LOL actually `2**3` == `2**3`.  Time to go to bed ;^)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `x % 2` in the `if`, not assigning back to `x`

```
if x % 2 == 0:
  ...
```

also at each iteration you should move over to next bit, otherwise you're adding the same bit over and over:

```
x = x >> 1
```